# Can't clone project with runner via SSH not HTTP

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I cant configure the .gitlab-ci.yml
Can you help me?
This is my config:

```
before_script:
  ## clean the working directory
  - BUILD_DIR="/C:/gitlab-runner/builds/"
  - CLONE_DIR="$BUILD_DIR/$CI_PROJECT_PATH"
  - cd $BUILD_DIR
  - rm -rf $CLONE_DIR
  - mkdir -p $CLONE_DIR

  ## clone the project each time (inefficient, consider performing fetch instead if it already exists)
  - git clone http://gitlab-runner:aZsZGxSJZLPnxZysDDQp@server:8888/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git $CLONE_DIR
  - cd $CLONE_DIR
tests:
    tags:
        - shell
        - ci
    script:
        - mvn test
```

I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwJPm.png)

Comment: Try using `export` on your variables. `export BUILD_DIR="/C:/gitlab-runner/builds/"`

Comment: @RickardKörkkö

Unfortunately another error
`export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and`

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/28624142/12409170

Comment: @RickardKörkkö
It helps, thank you a lot!

Comment: hmm now error is another.
I tried many variants with my path.
screen - https://prnt.sc/qq6d7p