# Self-hosted bitbucket runner not able to clone from repository

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to host a bitbucket Linux shell runner on my ec2 instance to run my pipeline (A really simple one). I have followed the steps and ran the scripts shown in the runner creation step. However, I am always getting `could not clone repository` error. From the runner log, I get:

```
Completing step with result Result{status=ERROR, error=Some(Error{key='runner.bitbucket-pipelines.clone-failure', message='We couldn't clone the repository. Try rerunning the pipeline.', arguments={}})}.
```

And from the pipeline UI, I can see:
`+ GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone --branch="master" --depth 50 https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME.git $BUILD_DIR fatal: destination path '/home/ec2-user/atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner/bin/../temp/8a6b3abd-f934-5a86-b666-e9dcf693d074/build' already exists and is not an empty directory.`.
The pipeline script:

```
      ...
       - step:
         name: 'runner'
         runs-on:
           - self.hosted
           - linux.shell
           - asg
         script:
           - echo "testing runner"
```

I have checked `../temp/8a6b3abd-f934-5a86-b666-e9dcf693d074/build` directory on my ec2 instance and it does not even exist. I have configured the ssh keys and I can `git clone` the repository on my ec2 instance without any problem. But somehow the runner cannot clone the repo.

I am stuck on this issue for days. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See if the runner is really running (a) on the machine you think it should and (b) not simultaneously with *another* runner that's created that directory temporarily. I have no idea why either might be the case, but those might explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked `../temp/8a6b3abd-f934-5a86-b666-e9dcf693d074/build` directory on my ec2 instance and it does not even exist.

It might not exist because if is a temporary folder deleted immediately after the pipeline run.

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59820141/6309), you can try and:

- define the build folder
- clean its content first
- then proceed with the rest of the existing pipeline.

That will not use a "`before_script`" directive, since [BitBucket does not have it](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-13773).

So try and add a first step which does not depend on your repository, and would

```yaml
script:
  - echo "cleanup BUILD_DIR '${BUILD_DIR}'"
  - rm -rf $BUILD_DIR
  - mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
```

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20143114/user20143114) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926013/self-hosted-bitbucket-runner-not-able-to-clone-from-repository/73932068#comment130559137_73932068):

> I just rebooted the instance and reconfigured the environment and it magically worked

That means it needed at least one run to "initialize" the environment, which persists after a reboot.

> running docker commands in the pipeline gives me "`The Docker feature is not supported on this self-hosted runner's platform`" error.

Double-check "[Deploying Docker containers on ECS](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/)" for the relevant pre-requisites.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just rebooted the instance and reconfigured the environment and it magically worked... i didn't change a thing.. But i have a new issue, which is running `docker` commands in the pipeline. It gives me `The Docker feature is not supported on this self-hosted runner's platform` error. I have installed docker on my ec2 and used `services: -docker` in the pipeline ...

Comment: @user20143114 Interesting. I have edited the answer accordingly.